# SSL infinite redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

so we recently added an SSL cert to one of our addon domains, but it caused every domain on the server to forward to it. I was able to get it to stop by adding the following to my .htaccess file, but now I get an infinite redirect loop and I have no idea how to fix it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^implantwideseminars\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any help at all would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

`RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on`

here you're saying that if it's NOT on SSL, it should redirect to `http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1`

notice the missing `s` on `http` ?

Try with:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^implantwideseminars\.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```